# Authorising to Instagram API strictly as an app (without user context)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to make periodic requests to Instagram API to fetch public data(GET /users/(user_id)), to track number of followers. not as an authorised Instagram user in my app but strictly as my app. (like in Facebook API, you create an app, create token and your all good to go)

I read all the official API docs and I guess my questions are:

1. Is this legit according to Instagram Policy?
2. If so, what are the chances of getting successful app review?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it does not meet the 3 approved usecases

Answer (score 1):

I think it's illegal it breaks the terms of service.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/  Which point you think my app brakes? 16? 19?